# Ace editor selects an entire line by default

Tags: ace-editor

Ace editor by default selects an entire line..

For eg: When the page loads up the first line is selected by default.

Also when I click anywhere in the screen that entire line gets selected..

How can I disable this feature..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure it's selection and not active line highlight? try doing

```
editor.setOption("highlightActiveLine", false)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of ace you should use the following method.

`editor.setHighlightActiveLine(false);`

http://ace.c9.io/api/editor.html#Editor.setHighlightActiveLine

Answer (score 1):

For all the People looking to deactivate the highlighting on the linenumber part (left of the textarea): This gets disabled with the `editor.setHighlightGutterLine(false);`
method.